# Cassandra 3.11.2 startup returning ConfigurationException "Unable to find authenticator class 'com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator'"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

i am trying to start Apache Cassandra 3.11.2 on Centos 7 and i get error

```
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Unable to find authenticator class 'com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator'
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.classForName(FBUtilities.java:556)
        ... 8 more
ERROR [main] 2023-02-21 14:22:24,788 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to find authenticator class 'com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator'
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.classForName(FBUtilities.java:560)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:593)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.newAuthenticator(FBUtilities.java:536)
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.AuthConfig.applyAuth(AuthConfig.java:53)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:154)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:137)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.applyConfig(CassandraDaemon.java:680)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:622)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:786)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.classForName(FBUtilities.java:556)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

(attached screen)[image]

Comment: Please post text information as text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, Cassandra is not able to find the authenticator class `com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator`:

```
Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Unable to find authenticator class 'com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator'
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator
```

That authenticator is only available in [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) so the open-source version of Cassandra doesn't know anything about it.

Just replace it with [the open-source version of the password authenticator](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/configuration/cass_yaml_file.html#authenticator):

```
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
```

In case you are following instructions from the [DataStax Docs](https://docs.datastax.com/) website, be aware that some of the docs only apply to specific products so either (a) view [the section specifically for open-source Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/cassandraAbout.html) or go to [the official Apache Cassandra website](https://cassandra.apache.org/). Cheers!

Comment: replaced in cassandra.yaml file:
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator

# Authorization backend, implementing IAuthorizer; used to limit access/provide permissions
# Out of the box, Cassandra provides org.apache.cassandra.auth.{AllowAllAuthorizer,
# CassandraAuthorizer}
authorizer: PasswordAuthorizer

Comment: Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: Unable to find authorizer class 'org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthorizer'
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthorizer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthorizer

Comment: There is no such thing as `PasswordAuthorizer`. The correct one is `CassandraAuthorizer` which is in the comment you posted. 

Comment: new error message:
ERROR [main] 2023-02-22 11:19:03,067 NativeLibraryLinux.java:64 - Failed to link the C library against JNA. Native methods will be unavailable.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna-1073564104/jna8760917299733827163.tmp: /tmp/jna-1073564104/jna8760917299733827163.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
WARN  [main] 2023-02-22 11:19:03,067 StartupChecks.java:136 - jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
ERROR [main]CassandraDaemon.java:803 - The native library could not be initialized properly